# uninstall wine permanently from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: windows, wine, winetricks

I recently used wine in `Ubuntu 16.04` for gaming purpose but It seemed to me that minute viruses attacked on my laptop through wine, so I am using these below commands

> sudo apt-get --purge wine
>
> sudo apt-get --purge remove wine

but when I do `wine --version` after executing above cmds terminal shows installed wine version
So do type this in terminal for removing wine completely

> dpkg -l | grep wine | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt-get purge -s

but if this will not work then replace -s with -y

Comment: How did you install wine ? What makes you think you have a virus ? Did you run wine as root ? You should be able to simply run `rm -rf ~/.wine` to remove all of your wine data.

Answer (score 0):

If You are sure you installed wine from terminal, You should run

```
sudo apt-get --purge wine*
```

If You are using playonlinux, run

```
sudo apt-get --purge playonlinux
```

Comment: I think you mean `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine*`